# Aperture Settings not Available in Blender 2.79

Tags: animation

I have noticed from other posts that I do not have the aperture settings available.
I am trying to set up depth of fields.
here is a screen shot of my screen....
as you can see the aperture settings are not there like I see on other screen shots.[image: screen shot of aperture settings]

Comment: the camera is selected. Still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the camera and be on the camera section of the properties window.

[image]

Aperture settings are available on Cycles only, not in blender internal-

Comment: Thanks. That solved one problem. Still need to get it working right in Blender Render mode.